# Codeigniter POST Form Submit Problems

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I just started learning CI and PHP and wanted to make a simple CRUD application.

I created a function to add a record, but when i submit the data in the form, Chrome downloads a file with no extension.

Controller

```
<?php

class Options extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('options_view');

}

function create()
{
    $data = array(

        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'));

    $this->data_model->addItem($data);
    $this->index();
}

}
```

Model

```
<?php

class Data_model extends CI_Model {
function getAll() {
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items");
if($q->num_rows() >0){
    foreach($q->result() as $row){
        $data[]=$row;
    }
}
return $data;
}

function addItem($data){
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    return;
}
}
?>
```

View

```
<html><head></head><body>
<style type="text/css">
label {display: block;}
</style>


<h2>Create</h2>
<?php echo form_open('options/create'); ?>

<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">Price</label><input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something that i did wrong?
No errors pop out. The form is created, but when i add data in the textboxes and click submit, the browser dowloands a "Create" file.

Comment: is the value inserted to database or not?

Comment: The value is not inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you don't need the last slash in that line?

```
<?php echo form_open('options/create/'); ?>
```

Comment: I edited that, but the issue still occurs. Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Check the generated HTML source in the browser - is the <form action="/options/create"> there? Another thing - you check $this->input->post, but from the view - is the form really created with method="post"?

Comment: The form is generated as so:   <form action="http://localhost/CI/index.php/options/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: Is that ; after options/create" really needed? Could it be cause of the trouble? And accept-charset is also not needed, I think. An idea - try to load plain <form action="" method="post"> instead of form_open() and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I manually added the form and now it works. So the CI form helper is a bit buggy?

Comment: Not sure what whas the error here. form_open() usually works for me, but don't produce that "accept-charset" or that semicolon. Anyway, glad we found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to load form helper like

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: I didnt load the form and url helper in there because i added them to autoload.php.   $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->load->model('data_model');` to method before `$this->data_model->addItem($data);`