# CodeIgniter form downloading file, instead of submitting the form

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am facing a strange issue and couldn't find a solution. I tries to search for the solution and come up with the link:
[Codeigniter POST Form Submit Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360503/codeigniter-post-form-submit-problems).
But it didn't help any way. Why am i unable to submit form to *myController/Function*? Instead of it remains on the same page and downloads *Function* file.

my form is

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url().$path;?>LoginAccount" method="post"  class="form-horizontal">                                  
        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" required  value="<?php if($cook_check){ echo $cook_val->Email; } ?>" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Email_address');?>" >
        </div> 
        <div style="margin-bottom: 0px" class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
          <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" required placeholder="<?php echo lang('Password');?>" value="<?php if($cook_check){ echo $cook_val->Password; }?>">
        </div>
        <p class="data-encrypted"><?php echo lang('Your_data_is_encrypted');?></p>

        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input  type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"  <?php if(get_cookie('remember')){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> <?php echo lang('Remember_me');?>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <input type="submit" id="btn-login" name="login" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo lang('Login');?>"> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be some configuration error on the web server side. 
PHP files are not downloaded normally but executed. Also the file you download should be empty (is it?) since everything in the controller should be wrapped in `<?php` tags, so no PHP code should be outputted to the file you download.

Post more details

- browser logs (in chrome press F12 -> *Network* tab) - request headers, response headers,
- an example of your HTML/JavaScript code (wrap it in CODE tags).

Comment: The site url is https://www.taloob.com/account, goto the login tab, randomly enter anything and click login

Comment: *Email does not exist* - the page works correctly, doesn't download but reloads the page with the error message

Comment: Okay, thanks @Andri. May be then it is some browser restriction by my side

Comment: @Sufyan I hope you were able to solve the issue. Maybe try another browser. If this was useful please accept my answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are over 50 rep, this would be a comment and no answer. And hint: do not ask for accepting your answer!